# can not find SoapClient in php

Tags: php, soap-client

I got this error saying:

Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in ....php file. Do I have to install/include the SoapClient manually? Isn't it a builtin php module?

Update:
If I am using wordpress, how can I get soapclient installed?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you'll either have to compile PHP with SoapClient enabled or modify your php.ini to enable the Soap extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you installed PHP.

If PHP was built from source, you have to rebuild it with the `--enable-soap` option per http://php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php.

If you installed a binary package via a package manager in your distro, check if you can find any `php5-soapclient`-packages or similar and install those.

Tested on Debian wheezy, `php5-cli` includes `SoapClient()` by default.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't installed by default. You need to install PHP with --enable-soap option.

Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php